# Issue with proxy done with sockets

Tags: java, sockets, http, url, proxy

I have a problem with this piece of code but I'm not able to see where is the error.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class Server {


public void startServer() {
    final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();

}

private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;

    private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            // Read request
            InputStream incommingIS = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[8196];
            int len = incommingIS.read(b);

            if (len > 0) {
                System.out.println("REQUEST"
                        + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "-------");
                System.out.println(new String(b, 0, len));

                // Write request
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
                OutputStream outgoingOS = socket.getOutputStream();
                outgoingOS.write(b, 0, len);

                // Copy response
                OutputStream incommingOS = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                InputStream outgoingIS = socket.getInputStream();
                for (int length; (length = outgoingIS.read(b)) != -1;) {
                    incommingOS.write(b, 0, length);
                }

                incommingOS.close();
                outgoingIS.close();
                outgoingOS.close();
                incommingIS.close();

                socket.close();
            } else {
                incommingIS.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

This code tries to simulate a HTTP proxy using sockets, the code receives the URL, process it and get back again to the browser untouched.
The problem is that the browser hangs, nothing is returned...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct way to write a proxy. An HTTP proxy receives a CONNECT command, which tells it to connect to an upstream target. So the first thing you have to do is read one line, do the upstream connect, and return an appropriate status. If the status was OK, you then have to start two threads to copy bytes between upstream and downstream, one in each direction, closing both sockets when you have received EOS from both of them.